# When i declare property how to use it

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, rdf, rdfa, rdfs

I use RDF/XML to represent some data.

First of all i want to show that a person knows other person, i declare the property and i use the following code to specify that mark knows katrin and katrin knows john

```
PART 1
<rdf:Property rdf:about="Know">
     <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Person"/>
     <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#Person"/>
</rdf:Property>


PART2
<rdf:Description rdf:about="#Mark">
    <dc:Knows rdf:resource="#Katrin"/>
</rdf:Description>  


<rdf:Description rdf:about="#Katrin">
    <dc:Knows rdf:resource="#John"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

Now i want to declare a property and represent more things. What i mean. I want to say for example that katrin owns a dog with ID 10 where this dog has colour black and its name is Peter.
Above i had only the resource the property and the object. Now that i have to say more how can i make it the part 2??

```
PART 1

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="Own">
     <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Person"/>
     <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#Dog"/>
</rdf:Property>

PART 2  ?????
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no different than your previous example

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/Katrin">
   <ns:owns rdfs:resource="http://example.org/dog/10"/>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/dog/10">
    <ns:name>Peter</ns:name>
    <ns:color>Black</ns:name>
</rdf:Description>
```

You might consider using a common vocabulary, such as FOAF, for relations such as `knows`, or `name`.  You should also use pretty much any other RDF serialization *other* than the XML serialization; it's hard to read and even harder to write.  I strongly suggest Turtle.